# Flutter: seperate scrollable views in the same screen

Tags: flutter, layout, widget

[image]

Hi, I want to have the similar scrollable widgets in one screen. I did research the SingleChildScrollView and NestedScrollView but I found they cannot have the result I want as the picture illustrated above. The scrollable items on the top is like a ListView while the large container below is more like a pageview that will scroll the whole container with 4 small containers to be swiped horizontally. Thanks a lot.

Comment: PageView is for when you want to scroll thru different pages, not for a partial scroll. I think you should be able to do it with a ListView. (Also, you don't really ask a question)

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure that the ListView can separate these two parts in the same screen?

Comment: That I am not, sorry. But give it a go!